# Tomcat slow startup due to hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Currently using Tomcat 6 and hibernate 3 for my application but I notice the startup is very slow,I only have about 40 entities mapped. Not sure if this is caused by hibernate the logs are below:

It takes around 5 mins for the below:

Any ideas? btw I have already tried increasing tomcat memory

```
2016-03-01 09:18:53,933  INFO [main] SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(105) | Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2016-03-01 09:24:42,046 DEBUG [main] GnrlLookupView.<clinit>(37) | Registering view: GnrlLookupView
2016-03-01 09:24:46,881  INFO [main] QuartzScheduler.<init>(209) | Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.0 created.
```

Hibernate config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"> <ref bean="dataSource" /> </property>
    <property name="mappingJarLocations">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/lib/*-hbm.jar</value>
        </list> 
    </property>
    <property name="lobHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
            <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>     
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>  <!-- Explicitly enabled 2nd level cache since upgrade to hibernate version 3.2.x -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref bean="entityAuditInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) --> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>ref bean="entityAuditInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) --> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**: I've enabled finer logging and came to the below, it prints out the below for 5 mins, any idea?

```
SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(316) | Opening Hibernate Session
2016-03-01 10:46:45,468 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string
2016-03-01 10:46:45,468 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string
2016-03-01 10:46:45,468 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string
2016-03-01 10:46:45,483 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string
2016-03-01 10:46:45,483 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string
2016-03-01 10:46:45,483 DEBUG [main] OracleLobHandler.getClobAsString(229) | Returning Oracle CLOB as string

2016-03-01 10:44:43,487 DEBUG [main] HibernateTemplate.flushIfNecessary(389) | Eagerly flushing Hibernate session
2016-03-01 10:44:43,487 DEBUG [main] SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(789) | Closing Hibernate Session
2016-03-01 10:44:43,487 DEBUG [main] SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(316) | Opening Hibernate Session
```

Comment: Is debug logging enabled for all packages (*)? If yes, maybe try to re-run the whole thing with trace logging, maybe it will reveal what is happening in those 5-6 minutes between `SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(105)` and `GnrlLookupView.<clinit>(37)`.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? How much memory do you have allocated? how much physical memory do you have on the box?

Comment: using java 1.6, this is my config on startup: -server -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

Comment: @NándorElődFekete yes logging is enabled i can see the initializiation of the entities on startup only on this particular line it just stops and takes really long

Comment: It's not clear at all what is happening **after** the `SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(105)` line. When that log message appears it might have already left the `SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance()` method and nothing points to what is taking up the time right after that log line. The next log line comes from the `GnrlLookupView` which I suppose is a proprietary class of yours. Making the log more verbose should be revealing. If not, try pausing the whole VM, find the thread which initializes the Spring context and try to step/debug over it.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete - good idea, i guess will just have to do the brute force way of it. Any suggestion where is a good start to trace for spring context?

Comment: I strongly believe that your logging is not set up to log on the finest level for every possible logger. Changing the log configuration would be my first step.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete you are right, I've enabled more detailed logging and I saw what's taking it so long, I've updated the question.

Comment: Well, this doesn't exactly reveal the actual problem, but it shows that something is getting called repeatedly for many-many times. Next step is to break into that method with a breakpoint and going up the stack frame until you find something meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer not due to hibernate settings, seems during startup application was loading lots of table and trying to save in cache.